# Get checkbox checked value

Tags: javascript, html

How do I retrieve checkboxes value individually for redirection of the page. I want to be able to redirect user after they've checked 2 checkboxes; then automatically redirect with it's value as a payload.

```
<script>
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);

        $box.prop("checked", true);
        var1 = $("input:checkbox[name='fooby[1][]']")
        var2 = $("input:checkbox[name='fooby[2][]']")

        if (($(var1).is(":checked")) & ($(var2).is(":checked"))) {
            window.location.href = url + 'var1=' + var1.value + '?var2=' + var2.value
        }
    } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm  trying to redirect user with two payloads - I can't mix var2 with var1 either; it needs to be constant, their values should be sorted accordingly.
When I do this.value it only gives me ONE value which is the last checked value. How can I get 2 different values?

This is var1 for instance

```
<center><input  style="display:block"type="checkbox" id="group1" class="radio" value="SINGLE_EXAM" name="fooby[1][]" />
```

and this is var2 for instance

```
<center><input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="Long Beach" id="group4" name="fooby[2][]" />    <label for="group4">dTLA</label>
```

I'm trying to get 2 different values; I tried adding everything to an array; it didnt work out since var1 could be var2 if I do that. How do I fix this?

Comment: Whatever is in the post is quite litterarly the relevant source. I'm trying to see if those 2 checkboxes are checked then redirect like shown in the code with its relevant checkbox value.

Comment: you are using bitwise operator ( & ) instead of logical ( && ) for your if condition, along with that var1 and v2 are already jQuery object, you dont need to do $(var1) and $(var2), just use var1.is(...) and var2.is(...)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have shown a working example using code snippet (where people could reproduce the issue) so that there would have been better clarity about what you are trying to achieve.

Now, the main problem you are facing is because you are using `var1.value` and `var2.value`. But those variables are JQ objects. So you should be using `.val()`.

Then, you should have selected only `:checked` checkboxes in `var1` and `var2` that would give you the correct value of selected option.

Btw, you are using `url + 'var1=' + var1.value + '?var2=' + var2.value`.

Do you mean to use `url + '?var1=' + var1.value + '&var2=' + var2.value`

As you have not shown a working example, I'm taking liberty to assume some HTML as shown below.

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
    var url = 'http://example.com/';
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);

        $box.prop("checked", true);
        var1 = $("input:checkbox[name='fooby[1][]']:checked")
        var2 = $("input:checkbox[name='fooby[2][]']:checked")
        
        if (($(var1).is(":checked")) & ($(var2).is(":checked"))) {
          console.log(url + 'var1=' + var1.val() + '?var2=' + var2.val());
          // window.location.href = url + 'var1=' + var1.value + '?var2=' + var2.value
        }
    } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="radio" value="SINGLE_EXAM" name="fooby[1][]" />    <label for="group1">Single Exam</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="group2" class="radio" value="MULTIPLE_EXAM" name="fooby[1][]" />    <label for="group2">Multiple Exams</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="group3" class="radio" value="NO_EXAM" name="fooby[1][]" />    <label for="group3">No Exam</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="Long Beach" id="group4" name="fooby[2][]" />    <label for="group4">dTLA</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="Medium Beach" id="group5" name="fooby[2][]" />    <label for="group5">eTLA</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="Short Beach" id="group6" name="fooby[2][]" />    <label for="group6">fTLA</label>
```